# Rails 4 - define javascript array from current data without reloading web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my rails 4 app I am trying to validate uniqueness of tags using jquery validate before users can add tags to an item.  The tag list looks like this:

```
<div id="taglist">
  <span class="label label-default tag-container">
    <a class="item-tag" id="veritatis" href="/tags/veritatis">veritatis</a>
  </span>
  <span class="label label-default tag-container">
    <a class="item-tag" id="id" href="/tags/id">id</a>
  </span>
  <span class="label label-default tag-container">
    <a class="item-tag" id="facere" href="/tags/facere">facere</a>
  </span>
  <span class="label label-default tag-container">
    <a class="item-tag" id="boo" href="/tags/boo">boo</a>
      <span>
        <a class="remove-tag-button" data-tag-name="boo" data-remote="true" href="">×</a>
      </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

My custom validator looks like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "tagUniqueness",
    function (value, element) {
      var tags_list = ;
      console.log(tags_list.indexOf(value));
      return this.optional( element ) || (tags_list.indexOf(value) == -1);
    }, "Tag already exists.");
```

When users add or remove tags the html displaying the tag list is updated using ajax with this partial.

```
<% item.all_tags_list.each do |t| %>
  <span class="label label-default tag-container">
    <%= link_to t, tag_path(t), class: "item-tag", id: t %>
    <% if item.tags_from(current_user).include?(t) %>
      <span>
        <%= link_to "×", '', class: "remove-tag-button", :'data-tag-name' => t, remote: true %>
      </span>
    <% end %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

I need a way to define a `tags_list` array in my custom validation method that will change based on the current tags list.

Ideally this would probably be gotten from the model but I don't know if this is possible.  My next thought is to get it from attributes from the html being generated by the partial.

Since the partial is being generated from the model, then if I am defining the array based on attributes form the partial it seems like it would be the same thing.  Im not sure how to do this.  I'm hoping it is possible in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data attributes...

```
<div id="tag-list" data-tag-list="<%= item.all_tags.map(&:name) %>">
</div>
```

Then, in your JavaScript you can refer to the data item:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "tagUniqueness",
    function (value, element) {
      var tags = $('#tag-list').data('tag-list').split(',');
      console.log(tags);
      ...
```

I don't know what the name of your element is, but you get the idea. It should be easy to grab them.

You can use a helper if you need to apply any transformations to the tags before you output them.

Comment: Could I do `var tags_list = $('#taglist').data('tag_list');`?

Comment: @user4584963 Try it :) - but yes you can. Only make sure your `data('tag-list')` matches the declaration `data-tag-list="#{item...`. In other words `tag_list` is not equal to `tag-list`.

Comment: #{} didn't work for me but <%= %> did.  Using `data-tag-list="<%= item.all_tags_list %>"` didn't return an array of strings like I wanted so I had to append .split(', ') in the tags declaration in javascript.

Comment: @user4584963 duh! Sorry, that was a brain-fart on my part. I gave you string interpolation instead of ERB. I'll update my answer.